# How to - proper WordPress 301 redirects?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, redirect, htaccess

I need to 301 redirect:
`example.com/service-1.html` to `example.com/our-services/1/`.

I've tried redirect plugins and `.htaccess`:

1. `Redirect  /service-1.html /our-services/1/`
2. `Redirect 301 /service-1.html http://www.example.com/our-services/1/`
3. `RewriteRule ^service\-1\.html$ /our-services/1/? [L,R=301]`
4. `RewriteRule ^(.*)/service-1.html$ http://www.example.com/our-services/1/$1 [R=301,L]`

But nothing is working, every time I'm redirected to (Woocommerce) product page `product/1`.

Wordpress `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be adding the directive to the wrong part of your `.htaccess` file? It needs to go at the top, before the existing WordPress directives. You should also use `RewriteRule` (ie. mod_rewrite) since you have existing mod_rewrite directives (the WP *front controller*).

Something like your 3rd attempt at the top of your `.htaccess` file should result in the appropriate redirect. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^service-1\.html$ /our-services/1/? [R=302,L]
```

Change to a 301 (if that is the intention) only when you are sure it's working OK. 301s are cached hard by the browser, so you will need to ensure the browser cache is cleared before testing.

The `?` on the end of the `RewriteRule` *substitution* simply removes the query string from the request. Whether this is required or not is up to you, but you don't have a query string in your example.

Comment: Thanks you, it is working. May I use only sugested code line or should be code embed  `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On </IfModule>`?

Comment: Yes, you can use just that one line of code at the top of the file before the `# BEGIN WordPress` block, providing there is a `RewriteEngine On` directive _somewhere_ in the file. You do not need to wrap it in an `<IfModule>` container. I would avoid changing what's inside the `# BEGIN WordPress` ... `# END WordPress` block simply because WordPress might overwrite it in a future update.

Comment: Thanks you. Because I need redirect a lot of links and there is possibility of changing category base name "our-services" in future, I have one additional question: Is it possible to have category base relative in .htaccess? "our-services" = woocommerce product category base.

Comment: You could potentially assign "our-services" to an environment variable and use that in your directives instead - if the idea is to prevent "our-services" being hardcoded in every directive? Or you could potentially change the `RewriteBase` directive and use relative _substitutions_? But note that `RewriteBase` will affect the entire file. (`RewriteBase` is not currently being used in the code you posted.)